# Cloudant search to return results within a document

Tags: lucene, cloudant

I'd like to be able to implement search for items in the *foo* array in documents that look like this:

```
{
  "_id":"...",
  "_rev":"...",
  "foo":
  [
    "This is some text", 
    "Another lot of text",
    "In fact there are lots and lots of these",
    ...
  ]
  ...
}
```

The *foo* array may contain up to several thousand items. There are several thousand documents.

I understand how to index and search items in the foo array (as per the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313815/creating-view-in-cloudant-couchdb-based-on-an-object-property-value)) but ideally I'd like a search to be able to return only the matched items in *foo* – not the whole of each document that contains a matched item.

I can process (whole-document) results to remove unmatched *foo* items, but is there a better way?